# Is $\sqrt{0.2}$ irrational

Tags: elementary-number-theory

We know that the $\sqrt 2$ is an irrational number.

Doing $\sqrt {.2} \approx .4472135955...$ in Wolfram Alpha gives the decimal approximation but it doesn't specify if it is accurately equivalent as a fraction of two integer numbers (a rational number).

If it is rational, how can I find its fraction equivalent.

Comment: Any irrational number can be approximated by a sequence of rational numbers. What does $\frac{2}{10}$ simplify to? Will you get an irrational number? Spoiler: yes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since  $\sqrt{5}$ is irrational and
$$\sqrt{0.2} =  \sqrt{\frac{2}{10}} =  \sqrt{\frac{1}{5}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\;,$$ 
$\sqrt{0.2}$ is irrational.

Answer (score 4):

To complete Mike's answer, let's prove that $\sqrt 5$ is irrational. This is a standard proof and worth remembering. You can apply it to other square roots too.

We shall proceed by assuming that $\sqrt 5$ is rational and demonstrate that this leads to a contradiction.

Let 
$$
\sqrt 5 = a/b
$$
where $a$ and $b$ are positive integers. Let us further assume that we are using the minimum such $a$ and $b$. That is, the fraction is in its lowest terms and $a$ and $b$ have no factor in common.

Then, squaring both sides we obtain
$$
5 = a^2/b^2
$$
Note that $a^2$ and $b^2$ also have no factors in common. Therefore the expression above is in its lowest terms and we may write 
$$
5 = a^2, 1 = b^2
$$
However, 5 is not the square of an integer, which contradicts the original hypothesis.

An alternate way to get to the contradiction is to note that $5|a^2$, and so $5|a$. So let 
$$
a = 5c
$$
where $c<a$. Substituing we obtain 
$$
5 = (5c)^2 / b^2
$$
and so
$$
1/5 = c^2 / b^2
$$
or, equivalently
$$
5 = b^2 / c^2
$$
Now we go through the argument again, setting $b = 5d$, $d<b$ to obtain
$$
5 = c^2 / d^2
$$
and 
$$
\sqrt 5 = c/d
$$
This is a contradiction, as we originally set $a/b$ to be the lowest terms, but now we have $d<b$

Comment: The claim that $\,a,b\,$ coprime $\,\Rightarrow\, a^2,b^2\,$ coprime is equivalent to what needs to be proved. Without any justifcation of that claim the proof is incomplete (or circular).

Comment: @Bill I find it very sad that you choose to flame a month-old post. You will note that I put the traditional proof below the quick one; that should be indicative that I don't particularly like using overly strong results in proofs. OK I didn't cite the F.T.A. but I don't feel that it is necessary to do so. Citing theorems turns maths from an intuitive art into a catalogue of facts, and that does nothing to encourage understanding.

Comment: It is important to point out gaps like this because they are often made by students. Some think that inference is obvious and requires no proof.  One of the goals of a course in elementary number theory is to teach students how to give *rigorous* proofs of statements that appear to be empirically or intuitively  obvious. Without a solid understanding of the key number theoretical properties underling such proofs, students will fail miserably once they move to higher degree number fields (where such properties generally fail).